# EF EntityTypeConfiguration WithMany using composite key

Tags: entity-framework

I'm working with a really old database design which has an old EF EDMX model and 2 tables.

```
Table 1:
Id
NodeId
ProviderId
StatusId
Date

Table 2:
Id
NodeId
ProviderId
StatusId
Date
UserId
Notes
```

In old edmx this has table 1 class with a property that has a collection of table 2.

The foreign key is a composite of NodeId/ProviderId from both tables. In table 1 it's unique and in table 2 it's duplicated.

I'm trying to re-do this in EF CodeFirst but I cannot figure out this 1 scenario.

How do I map this in the `EntityTypeConfiguration` mapping of Table 1?

When I map the history table I get:

[image]

But there's no way to define the foreign keys...

If I try to configure on with the configuration, like so:

Table 1

```
        HasMany(x => x.History)
            .WithRequired(x => x.ParentStatus)
            .HasForeignKey(x => new
            {
                x.NodeId,
                x.ProviderId
            });
```

And / Or (tried with both and individually)

```
        HasRequired(x => x.ParentStatus)
        .WithMany(x => x.History)
        .HasForeignKey(x => new
        {
            x.NodeId,
            x.ProviderId
        });
```

Both fail with:

One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

> ApprovalStatusBase_History_Source_ApprovalStatusBase_History_Target: :
>   The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a
>   relationship constraint must be identical.

I can't find anything more on this error.

Is it because both tables have their own primary keys but are joined by the composite keys?

This works in the old edmx :(

Comment: Have you tried to continue the fluent configuration (that's why it's called fluent:) by putting `.` after `HasMany(...)`, e.g. `HasMany(...).WithRequired(...).HasForeignKey(...)`

Comment: However keep in mind that `{NodeId, ProviderId}` must be a PK of the first table in order to be able to be used as FK from the second table. Except if you are using EF Core, do you?

Comment: @IvanStoev just updated, ah the primary keys of the tables are both just `.Id` but the tables are linked by composite keys.

Comment: Then see my second comment. I have no idea if that was possible with edmx (never used that), but I'm 100% sure it's not possible with Code First.

Comment: :'( damn, need to think of a work-around for this then.

Comment: As a workaround, you could try **mapping** `{NodeId, ProviderId}` as PK of the first table - even it's not in the db. As soon as it's unique (and immutable) and no FK referencing `Id` column, it could work. Good luck.